# How can I get a log file from an Android device when the issue makes the user pull the battery?

Tags: android, error-logging

I work on an app that runs fine on most Android devices; however, sometimes a user complains that the app repeatedly causes his device to freeze such that he has to pull the battery. What can I do to get a log file from this user so I can figure out what caused the freeze? Ordinarily we ask users to repro a crash and run CatLog immediately following to get a log; however, in this case running CatLog after the battery pull doesn't seem to get us any useful information in the log.

Comment: This doesnt make sense. If he pulls the battery out.. Android wont be running.. theres nothing to pull

Comment: You can't.  If you freeze u that badly, it probably isn't going to let logcat write to disk either. And a debugger would probably be broken too.  These are black box debugging type problems-  you need to figure out how to reproduce it and from that figure out what thing(s) are happening on all of your threads (and what threads should/are running), and use that to figure out what's broken.  The best bet is just to add a LOT of logging and it may give you an idea if something is unexpectedly running in the background causing problems or if you're entering an odd state.

Comment: Also, doing some hprof dumps and seeing if you're not deallocating resources that could take up CPU time would make sense, if you can anticipate when a crash is coming and do so beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

## Ask him to hit home and wait a minute or two.

If the device is slow, it might look frozen but it will respond. Android is designed to be robust.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal because each app runs in a sandbox and a device is not to crash unless you've messed with android internals. How isn't this helpful? Please retract your downvote.